# Inconsistent output of unicode strings with print and format()

Tags: python, unicode, format

I read a value from a database query that produces a unicode string. For reasons that are irrelevant here, the data-entry person entered the string value into the database as: "Assessor’s Parcel" (note the 'backward' apostrophe). I'm writing code that's just going through selected database records and printing out text. I use the .format() operation to insert the text from the variable into the printout. As we all know, .format fails when handed a unicode string. So, to reduce this to the conundrum, I submit the following example:

```
>>> a = u"Assessor’s Parcel"
>>> a
u'Assessor\u2019s Parcel'
>>> print a
Assessor’s Parcel
>>> "{0}".format(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

The above lines are from the 'Interactive Window' of PythonWin (PythonWin 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32.)

Why does 'print a' produce a different output than just 'a'? And why, if either of those can produce a reasonable output, .format() can't?

If I determine that I can't output unicode text (for some as yet unknown reason) and that I would be content with output that contains the "\u" syntax, then do I really have to wrap all my string outputs from database values in some code (method or otherwise) that does the conversion?

Comment: Obligatory link to http://bit.ly/unipain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [use unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type)! (notice that your error is the first example on that HOWTO)

The issue isn't with format, it's with the fact that you're trying to put a unicode object into a bytestring and so it's trying to encode it (using the default encoding which is ascii). If instead you tried to format it into a unicode literal there would be no problem..

```
>>> a = u"Assessor’s Parcel"
>>> '{}'.format(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> u'{}'.format(a)
u'Assessor\u2019s Parcel'
>>> print u'{}'.format(a)
Assessor’s Parcel
>>>
```

It would also not be an issue if you were putting a bytestring into a bytestring.

```
>>> '{}'.format(a.encode('utf8'))
'Assessor\xe2\x80\x99s Parcel'
>>> print '{}'.format(a.encode('utf8'))
Assessor’s Parcel
>>>
```

But that makes it more difficult to output to another (different) encoding later.

Answer (score 0):

Simply 'a' asks for the "most raw" form of the value, from the **repr** method of the class.  Print drives that value through the str() conversion.  The format expression sends it through yet a different conversion, one that is currently working in ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a few attempts of mine to print properly. `print a.encode('utf-8')` seems like the solution:

```
>>> a = u"Assessor’s Parcel"
>>> a
u'Assessor\u2019s Parcel'

>>> print a
Assessor’s Parcel

>>> "{0}".format(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)

>>> a.encode('utf-8')
'Assessor\xe2\x80\x99s Parcel'

>>> print a..encode('utf-8')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print a..encode('utf-8')
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> print a.encode('utf-8')
Assessor’s Parcel

>>> print a.encode('utf-8')
Assessor’s Parcel

>>> print a..encode('utf-8')
  File "<stdin>", line 1

    print a..encode('utf-8')
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> a.encode('utf-8')
'Assessor\xe2\x80\x99s Parcel'

>>> print a.encode('utf-8')
Assessor’s Parcel
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interactive shell, 'a' does print the representation of a. You can achieve the same with `print repr(a)`

`print a` will print `str(a)` to stdout. `print` will always encode the output the whatever the encoding of the output is. So `print a` is similar to `sys.stdout.write(a.encode(sys.stdout.encoding) + "\n")`

Please note the difference between `u"string"` and `"string"`. The first is a Unicode string - a sequence of a Unicode code points, while the later is a binary string - a sequence of bytes. Python 3 makes a much more rigid distinction between the two (I actually prefer Python 3 since it is more picky, and thus better at telling me what I did wrong)

In `"{0}".format(a)`, `"{0}"` is a binary string. You try to format a unicode string with non-ascii characters in that binary string. That failed because you need to tell Python how to convert from Unicode to binary string. So you can do: `"{0}".format(a.encode('utf-8'))`.

However, you may not want a formatted binary string, but instead a formatted Unicode string. In that case, you can write: `u"{0}".format(a)`